# Error NU1202 Package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x64.

Tags: sqlite, uwp, nuget-package

I've downloaded a working UWP solution targeting 16299 which I changed to target 14393 (Anniversary) so it would work on all Windows 10 Phones as well. Apart from the obvious errors where the solution uses newer W10 version methods and namespaces, I also get:
**Error NU1202  Package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x64.** (multiple times)

But according to https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/ Microsoft SQLite should work from 14393.

I've tried installing the oldest version number available (2.0.0 instaed of 2.1.0 now included) but that doesn't change the error.

How can I solve this problem?

Dick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sqlite.core** is the core version and will work only from fall creators update and above. if you want to use sqlite on older versions then you can see details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Comment: Thanks for the link; now it works! Using the instructions from section "The minimum version of your project does not target the Fall Creators Update" I finally was able to download a 1.x version of MS SQLite which is .Net Standard <1.5 and supporting 14393. Without these steps (re)installing SQLite using NuGet  did not show a version before 2.0.